# QueryDSL (with Spring Data JPA) automatically add predicate to issued queries

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Is it possible to automatically add a predicate to all queries issued by QueryDSL?

Since the predicate contains a dynamic ID Hibernate's `@Where` annotation is not enough for my use-case.

Is it possible to create a pre-filtered version of the `EntityPath` which retrieves the dynamic ID at runtime? Or are there any better suited approaches?